# Google Spreadsheet DLLs

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to build a C# application that communicated with the Google Docs API. I have found a great article on this here: http://codestrian.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/reading-google-docs-spreadsheets-in-c/

I downloaded the 3 required DLL's and imported them as referenced in Visual Studio. The inelisence is loading the proper content but Visual Studio still tells me that I'm missing a reference or assembly.

The three required dll's are:

```
Google.GData.Client;
Google.GData.Extensions;
Google.GData.Spreadsheets;
```

I am reading some similar threads about how this is a profiling issue. However, both my Solution and DLL's appear to be in .NET Framework 4. Has anyone ran into this issue with Google Dll's or similar dll's not being 'picked up' with Visual Studio? How do you get around it?

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;        
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

namespace myNamespace
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Devesh
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://test.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Devesh : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string getSpreadsheet()
    {
        SpreadsheetService myService = new SpreadsheetService("myApp");
        myService.setUserCredentials("test@gmail.com", "test");

        return "Nothing";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the Newtonsoft.Json library?

The dependencies list on the nuGet website list it as needed.

Comment: I did not import that. Is it needed? I downloaded the zip file for it but don't see any obvious "you need to import this one" files.

Comment: I added the newtonsoft.json as a reference but still getting the error 'The type or namespace name 'SpreadsheetService' could not be found

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the Google Data API installer or the Nuget Google.GData.Spreadsheets package?

Comment: I download the Google API Installer and it completed successfully. I then went into visual studio, added the references to the dll's and then started writing code and ran into the missing assembly/reference error. Did I miss a step?

Comment: I ran a quick test and tried to use the same code in one of my aspx code behind files. No issue there. However, when I use the same code in my asmx.cs file, i get the error. Can you not use these in a web service? Maybe that's my issue?

Comment: There are two 'flavors' of .NET 4: ".Net Framework 4 Client" and ".Net Framework 4".  I believe you need the full version: ".Net Framework 4"  (in the build settings).

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought too. However, I have my build as .Net Framework 4 right now. I see the option for the Client Framework but and I thought about switching it as a test. It's an entire web application so if I switch it, I'm thinking i'll break something in the process. However, the DLL's...how can I tell if they are Client Framework or just .Net 4 Framework? The web site doesn't say and my trial license for the reflector has expired (not sure if that'd even help me). Any advice and/or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Also, adding two important pieces of information that I have not mentioned 1.) This is a Web Service 2.) I tried creating a blank aspx page and doing everything in the code behind. That worked perfectly fine. So maybe Google API's don't support web services? I don't know how typical it is that a web service is calling another web service...

Comment: Since it is a web service, maybe you need the IIS application pool set to .NET Framework Version 4.0.